# Web services, architectural design advice for central logging

Tags: web-services, logging, architecture

We have a certain number of SOAP and REST Web Services, which provide legal information for clients. Management demands to log all the information which is requested by this services. Using logs they want to collect statistics and bill clients.

My colleague offered to use central relational database for logging. 
I don’t like this solution, because number of services are growing and I think such architecture will be bottleneck for productivity.

Can you advise me what architectural design will be good for such kind of task ?

Comment: This is what http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the central database will be a bottleneck, do you mean that it will be too slow to keep up with the logging requests?  Or are you saying you are expecting database changes for each logging request type?

I would define a more generic payload for logging (figure out your minimum standardized fields), and then create a database for those logs.

```
<log><loglevel>INFO</loglevel><systemName>ClientValueActualizer</systemName><userIp>123.123.123.432</userIp><logpayload><![CDATA[useful payload for billing]]</logpayload></log>
```

If you are worried about capacity, you could throw a queue in front of it, which would have the advantage of not bogging down the client if the logs are busy.

You can decouple the consumption of these messages into separate systems.  each of which can understand the various payloads.  The risk here is if you want to add new attributes, it will be difficult to control what systems are sending what.  But that's just a general issue with decoupled services.

Comment: When I say the central database will be a bottleneck, I mean that it will be too slow to keep up with the logging requests.

Comment: Oh, well that's easy, throw a queue in front of it.  Or switch to a NoSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider Apache Kafka as distributed commit log. This be good for performance wise as it scales out horizontally and it can deliver messages only when client pulls those messages.

Comment: Interesting product, but as I see it is quite young.  Have you used it in production ? Is it stable ?

Comment: What did you implement for the problem you have posted ? Did you try Kafka or other logging solutions.Hope you found my answer useful at that point of time